# I have an old screen from a portable dvd player - what type of input is this, and how to I convert it to DSI?

Tags: raspberry-pi, lcd, conversion

Here is my screen's datasheet: http://www.datasheet4u.com/mobile/640898/AT070TN07.html
What type of cable does this run of of, and how do I convert this to either dsi or gpio so I can use it with my raspberry pi?!? Please help - I've looked everywhere and found nothing

Comment: *"What type of cable..."* - page 2 of your linked datasheet says *"FPC Connector is used for the module electronics interface. The recommended model is FH19S-26S-0.5SH (51) manufactured by Hirose"*, it also gives the pinout and a summary of how it's expected to be driven. You can't easily plug-and-play without understanding those details. A quick look suggests to me that it's expecting analogue RGB signal levels, not digital. This all makes your question a little too broad for a quick answer. It might be worth seeing if it was originally connected to another driver board.

Comment: I looked for a driver board, all I could find was 002-FD70-05N8-00

Comment: So would there be an easy way to connect this to VGA?

Comment: Sometimes there are cheap VGA driver boards available on eBay.  I bought one a few years ago to drive the LCD panel from a laptop.  You usually have to specify the exact LCD model in order to ensure compatibility.  The one I got included both the VGA-to-LCD board and the backlight driver board.

Comment: Here is an example. Note that I'm not recommending this particular product for your particular LCD, but instead pointing you in the right direction: http://www.ebay.com/itm/DIY-HDMI-VGA-Driver-Board-HDMI-VGA-DVI-AUDIO-LVDS-LCD-Controller-Board-Kit-/201542257701?hash=item2eecdacc25:g:urIAAOSwa-dWpeVS

Comment: I have a board labeled  002-FD70-05N8-00. Is this of any use?

Comment: After some looking at parts, i have concluded that this was originally a TFDVD7006 toby dvd player

Comment: this helped a little: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=245&v=oaMJR1gpKD0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first attempt would be to set your Raspberry Pi's video output to something like 720P on HDMI and try one of these guys:

[http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA86X3DG8593&cm_re=hdmi_to_component_converter-*-9SIA86X3DG8593-*-Product](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA86X3DG8593&cm_re=hdmi_to_component_converter-_-9SIA86X3DG8593-_-Product)

With the center pin of red going to pin 22, the center pin of green going to pin 23, the center pin of blue going to pin 24 on the InnoLux chip and common all the outer parts of the RCA and connect them to pin 21 or pin 1 on the InnoLux.

This might be what the chip is looking for - if not, you've at least got the colors broken out so you can monkey with the signaling until the display understands it.

Comment: This helps a lot! My only question is if I could use a AUX to RCA cable? I have on of those laying around.

Comment: You could use a composite to component adapter with the component output on the Raspberry Pi or the adapter I already suggested, but an AUX to RCA cable is an audio cable and wouldn't help at all for this.

Comment: oh, that explains why when I put the AUX to RCA into an older monitor, it did nothing

Comment: Does the Raspberry Pi have an output on it that could be used for this? So I wouldn't need to but a converter? If necessary I can buy a converter, but would prefer not to.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi natively supports Composite video and HDMI via standard ports and also supports a somewhat proprietary connection for a Pi screen. None of these are suited for your display driver. You either need an adapter cable or you'd need to do something in software to emulate (poorly) an analog component signal. Here's a link to an ebay search with cables as cheap as $1.53 USD. http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=HDMI+component&rt=nc&LH_BIN=1

Comment: So my best bet is to either buy a RCA to HDMI converter or to use a composite to component adapter

Comment: This leaves one more question: is it a good idea to cut open the HDMI to RCA cable for easy access to the inside wires? of course, only after I have tested that this works by using rubber bands and alligator clips

Comment: HDMI to component. "RCA" refers to the connector type, not the signal going through it. Also, pay close attention to the word order, as most of the adapter cables are NOT bi-directional. You need "HDMI to component" or "composite to component". You may also want to pick up some RCA female jacks unless your DVD player had some you can reuse. Also, if you found my answer helpful, please do me the favor of upvoting my original answer.

Comment: I cant Upvote, but I checked it as solved

Comment: So CAN i cut open the cable o access the wires? Well ik i can, is it a good idea?